# ASP.NET: Access temp data in ViewBag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am beginner in ASP.NET and trying to get data in `ViewBag`by using temp data in controller. I got it in `user.Username` and `user.Email` but not getting in `ViewBag.Name` and `ViewBag.Email` respectively. My code is given below please guide me how can i get it in ViewBag?

QuestionsContoller.cs

```
public class temp {
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Question() {
    return View();
}
```

[HttpPost]

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

```
public ActionResult Question(User user) {
    temp temp_user = new temp();
    temp_user.email = user.Email;
    temp_user.username = user.Username;
    return RedirectToAction("Answers" , temp_user);
}

public ActionResult Answers(temp temp_user) {
    User user = new Models.User();
    user.Username = temp_user.username;
    user.Email = temp_user.email;
    ViewBag.Name = user.Username;
    ViewBag.Email = user.Email;
    return View(user);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"how can i get it in ViewBag?"_ ? Do you want to get your ViewBag data into your view ?

Comment: yes, after it I will get it in my View.

Comment: So you need to know to get the data into the View, right?

Comment: yes... I can call it in my View. But before it I want to get it in my ViewBag.

Comment: I realy don't understand what you need to do.

Comment: I want to get my data in ViewBag.Name and ViewBag.Email from user.Username or user.Email.

Comment: You _have_ gotten it into the ViewBag. `ViewBag.Name = user.UserName`.

Comment: No, I have gotten it in just user.UserName not in ViewBag.Name

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redirect with a payload. A redirect is an empty-bodied response with typically a 302 status code and a `Location` header indicating the URL that should be requested next. The client, upon receiving this type of response, will generally then go ahead and make a new request for that URL. Importantly, the client will not know or care to pass any additional data along with this request, so you cannot enforce that something like your `temp` object is included.

If you need to persist that data between requests, you can add it to `TempData`:

```
TempData["temp_user"] = temp_user;
```

And then fetch it in the action you redirect to via:

```
 var temp_user = TempData["temp_user"] as temp;
```

Alternatively (and preferably), you'd simply redirect with the user id in tow, and then simply look up the user again. The use of sessions (which `TempData` is) should be avoided as much as possible.

```
return RedirectToAction("Answers", new { userId = user.Id });
```